# Algorithm: to distribute n elements into m buckets, such that the maximum sum of elements among buckets is minimum

Tags: python, algorithm

The goal is to `minimize(max(bucket1,bucket2,...,bucketn))`

I have decided, that greedy approach must work:

```
def algo(values,k = 4):
  values_sort = sorted(values,reverse = True)#sorting values in descending order
  buckets = [[] for b in range(k)]#creating buckets

  for i in range(len(values_sort)):#If buckets are empty add biggest elements to them
    if i < k:
      buckets[i].append(values_sort[i])

    else:# Greedy approach
      sums = [sum(b) for b in buckets]
      index = sums.index(min(sums))#add new element to the local minimum(the smallest sum of time among all buckets)
      buckets[index].append(values_sort[i])

  return buckets
```

I have compared my greedy solution to the random assingment:

```
#random assingment to the buckets
def algo_random(time,k):
  buckets = [[] for k in range(k)]
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(time)):
    buckets[count].append(time[i])
    count +=1
    if count == k:
      count = 0

  return buckets
```

I ran the code bellow, where I compared greedy solution to the random assingment 1 million times:

```
for i in range(1000000):
  time = [uniform(0, 1000.0) for i in range(100)]
  #algo random
  rand = algo_random(time,4)
  t_rand = max([sum(x) for x in rand]) 

  #algo optimal
  algo_o = algo(time,4)
  t_o = max([sum(x) for x in algo_o])

  if t_rand < t_o:
    print('False')
```

And in 2 cases out of 1 million, random assingement was better than greedy solution. It means, that my algorithm(greedy solution) is not optimal. Can you help me to correct my algorithm?

**EDIT:** I have noticed, that algorithm works well for big number of records and bad for small number of records

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is (for some reason) known as the knapsack filling algorithm or knapsack problem - searching for this will get you a plethora of help.

Comment: @barny not quite, because I don't have any restriction(buckets can take unlimited number of values) and in knapsack problem there is only one bucket(not k)

Comment: The random assignment test is interesting. It suggests that a genetic algorithm would be effective in solving the problem. Or you could start with the greedy solution, and then incrementally improve it with a hill-climbing algorithm.

Comment: Or refer here under "multiple knapsack problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: You can find the optimal solution by combining a binary search with any exact algorithm that solves the [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Exact_algorithm).

Comment: @user3386109 it looks like in bin packing problem the goal is to minimize the number of bins used. In my case the goal is different. Or maybe I didn't get the point. If so, I would like to ask you about details.

Comment: Correct, bin packing minimizes the number of bins. I suggest that you guess the proper bucket size, and run bin packing. If bin packing uses more than N bins, the guess was too low, and you should try a larger size. Otherwise, the guess was either optimal, or too high, and you should try a smaller size. That's the basis for a **binary search** for the correct bin size. But to use a binary search, you need two initial sizes: a lower bound and an upper bound. Your greedy algorithm gives you the upper bound. The sum of the element sizes divided by the number of buckets gives you the lower bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is sometimes called the job shop scheduling problem and is known to be NP-hard, so there are no known greedy algorithms that run efficiently and always produce the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It means, that algorithm(any) that solves this problem optimally doesn't exists? Or only greedy agloritms don't work?

Comment: You can solve this problem optimally - for example, you could list all possible assignments and take the best - but there are no known polynomial-time algorithms for this problem.